# Wheel Collider Unity: after adding torque the vehicle starts moving sideways

Tags: unity-game-engine

I really killed few hours to try to fix this, Googling for a solution, but I could not.

I've got a vehicle, it's a go-cart, so there are no suspensions (technically there are, but the values are close to 0, to simulate the tires). The vehicle has a rigid body attached and the child object contains the 4 wheel colliders (and the model itself), as can be seen here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76599014/sxc/Clipboard01.jpg

For testing, I added a short script to make the vehicle move. It's in the GameObject called "gokart":

```
public class carControler : MonoBehaviour {

public WheelCollider fr, fl, rr, rl;
public float performance = 50f;

void FixedUpdate () {
    throttle();
}

public void throttle() {

    this.rl.motorTorque = this.performance;
    this.rr.motorTorque = this.performance;
} }
```

**What happens is**: the rear **wheels** start to **rotate**, as intended, but the **vehicle starts moving sideways slowly**. The movement speed depends on the torque amount (the wheel rotation in this case). There is **no movement forward**, so this is not the bug, where when you are standing on a flat surface you are drifting on the sides.

Any ideas? If you need a video or a GIF (I have to figure out how to make one) of the movement, I'll be glad to provide one.

Comment: hmm, are you sure that all axes on object and wheels point forward? (blue arrow means forward) check it on another, dummy car make it from boxes and cylinders and then look at results. if its problem with axes you will need to change their direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try and apply 0 brake torque to the front wheels while applying motor torque to the rear wheels.

```
public void throttle() {

this.rl.motorTorque = this.performance;
this.rr.motorTorque = this.performance;
this.fr.brakeTorque = 0f;
this.fl.brakeTorque = 0f;
}
```

That being said, anything could go wrong if the Rigidbody/wheelcolliders aren't set up correctly.  Unity's wheel colliders can be difficult to set up and work with. Unity changed the physics in Unity 5 so most documentations are outdated.

I found this very good short document that was made by unity: http://unity3d.com/profiles/unity3d/themes/unity/resources/downloads/beta/unity-5.0-user-guide.pdf

It highlights the changes that was made to unity 5 and at the end of page 5 you can find a section that explains how to set up a car. I have tried it about a month ago in a new unity project and it worked. the instructions are clear so try this tutorial out and I hope it will help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not having the image available I'm not a totally sure about the situation but my assumption based on your description is you should try increasing the sideways friction and tweak the forward friction a little bit according to your taste. You have to increase the sideways friction anyways as you are making a go-cart. As far as I know, most arcadey go-carts don't drift and behave a lot different from regular racing cars.
Hope that will solve the problem.